# Create trigger on dummy view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having problem creating a trigger. The database model look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Unit (
SerialNO    VARCHAR(3)
PRIMARY KEY (serialNO)
);

CREATE TABLE PackageConfig (
PartNO      VARCHAR(15),
SomeValue   VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (PartNO)
);

CREATE TABLE Package (
ID          INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Config      VARCHAR(15),
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Config) REFERENCES PackageConfig(PartNO)
);

CREATE TABLE UnitInPackage (
Package     INT,
Unit        VARCHAR(3),
PRIMARY KEY (Package,Unit),
FOREIGN KEY (Package) REFERENCES Package(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Unit) REFERENCES Unit(SerialNO)
);
```

There are `Units`, `PackageConfigurations` and `Packages`. A package has exactly one `PackageConfiguration` and the relation between `Package` and `Unit` is a many (units) to at most one (package).

What I'm trying to accomplish is a trigger on a view that would let me do the following (assuming that the `PackageConfig` and `Units` exist):

```
INSERT INTO v_MultiUnitPackage (PackageConfig, Unit1, Unit2, Unit3) 
VALUES ('SomeConfig','abc','bcd','cde');
```

Which inside the trigger would do something like:

```
DECLARE @last INT;

INSERT INTO Package (Config) VALUES ('SomeConfig');
SET @last = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
INSERT INTO UnitInPackage (Package,Unit)
VALUES (@last,'abc'),(@last,'bcd'),(@last,'cde');
```

Or for more columns:

```
INSERT INTO Package (Config) VALUES ('SomeConfig');
SET @last = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
INSERT INTO UnitInPackage (Package,Unit)
VALUES (@last,'hgf'),(@last,'gfe'),(@last,'fed'),(@last,'edc'),(@last,'dcb'),(@last,'cba');
```

To summarize, I'd like to create a trigger that takes a `PackageConfig` and N-number of `Units` and insert them in the corresponding tables.

I've been looking into creating a dummy view that simply has the correct data types and a great enough number of columns to allow for the number of Units I want but didn't find a solution.

I also looked into something like grouping by `Package.ID` and for each group selecting the first unit that hasn't already been selected to a previous column. Since `GROUP BY` is only usable with aggregate functions I'm unsure how to realize this idea.

Realistically I don't see ever needing more than 5 or so Units but would prefer a generic solution to my problem.

Perhaps there is a really simple solution that I'm just not seeing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert with a view is one way of doing it, so you just need to have your dummy view update with the number of units you need. Here is how the trigger should looks like:

```
create  view v_MultiUnitPackage
as
select 'Some-Config' as PackageConfig, 'abc' as Unit1, 'bcd' as Unit2, 'cde' as Unit3
go

  create TRIGGER tg_I_v_MultiUnitPackage
ON v_MultiUnitPackage 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @last INT;

    INSERT INTO Package (Config)
    SELECT inserted.PackageConfig
    FROM inserted
    SET @last = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO UnitInPackage (Package,Unit)
    SELECT @last, inserted.Unit1
    FROM inserted;

    INSERT INTO UnitInPackage (Package,Unit)
    SELECT @last, inserted.Unit2
    FROM inserted;

    INSERT INTO UnitInPackage (Package,Unit)
    SELECT @last, inserted.Unit3
    FROM inserted;
END
```

A better option in my opinion, would be passing the units to a stored procedure as XML and handle the insert there. Here is how the procedured should looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_i_PackageUnits
(
    @PackageConfig varchar(15),
    @Units xml -- <root><unit>abc</unit><unit>bcd</unit><unit>cde</unit>
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @last INT;
    INSERT INTO Package (Config) VALUES (@PackageConfig);
    SET @last = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO UnitInPackage (Package,Unit)
    select node.value('(.)[1]', 'VARCHAR(3)') from @xml.nodes('/root/unit')as result(node)

END
```

Comment: I'll check out the stored procedure solution tomorrow. 

Do you have an example of how to create the view for that trigger in case I have to fall back on that option?

Comment: it is updated on the answer, but I would try to get the stored procedure working ... much better solution IMHO.